# Temperature at which a copper cable brakes up

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, ratio

A power cable of copper is stretched straight between two fixed towers.
If the temperature decreases, the cable tends to contract . The amount of contraction for a free copper cable or rod is
0.0017% per degree centigrade. Estimate what temperature decrease will
cause the cable to snap. Pretend that the cable obeys young moduli until it reaches
its breaking point. Ignore the weight of the cable and the sag and stress produced by the weight.

I was trying:
$$\frac{\Delta L}{L} = \frac{F}{AY}$$

the ultimate strenght of copper and youg modulus are:

$$ U_s = 2.4\times10^8 $$
$$Y = 11\times10^{10}$$

I also notice:
$$\Delta L \propto C°$$
then:

$$C° = \frac{U_s}{Y}L$$

however I dont have L does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Notice how in the equation the ultimate strenght became the pressure at wich the cable brakes up

Comment: Ultimate strength is the pressure at wich the cable brakes up

Comment: What are $F$ and $A$ in your first equation?

Comment: @JonathanPal Force and cross sectional area

Comment: ok! If I'm understanding correctly, we would then have $\frac{\Delta L}{L} = \frac{U_s}{Y}$ at the point when the cable begins to break?

Comment: @JonathanPal thats correct

Comment: @mathlove I am sorry sir but my previous account was suspended from posting so I have to create a new one

Comment: @mathlove your answer is indeed intuitive and correct

Comment: I dont remember the password of that account but I think you would like this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4693213/1177689

Comment: @mathlove diffcicult to recover because I log out of gmail I own you 50 points but I can give you upvote and answer in the upper question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the equation $\frac{\Delta L}{L} = \frac{U_s}{Y}$, we then have that at the point when the cable breaks, $\frac{\Delta L}{L} \approx \frac{2.4 \times 10^8}{11 \times 10^{10}} \approx 0.00218 = 0.218\%$.

So given the contraction is $0.0017\%$ per degree centigrade, i.e. $\frac{\Delta L}{L} = 0.000017 * \Delta T$ (where $T$ is temperature), then we get that $\Delta T = \frac{0.00218}{0.000017} \approx 128$. So the temperature would need to decrease by about 128 degrees Celsius (quite a large amount) in order for the cable to snap. Hopefully I'm understanding this problem correctly; I haven't worked with these ideas in physics in quite a while.

Comment: You are smart, thank you sir

Comment: I'm flattered! Happy to help.