# How much would the diamter of a pipe increase after some pressure?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, ratio

A pipe of mild steel with a wall 0.4 cm thick and a diameter of 50 cm
contains a liquid at a pressure of 2 X 10^4 N/m2. How much will the diameter of the pipe expand due to this pressure?

I was trying:

$$p = \frac{\Delta V}{V}B$$
since steel is isotropic :
$$p = \frac{\Delta d}{3d}B$$
hence:
$$\Delta d = \frac{p3d}{B}$$

but I got the wrong answer. the true answer must be around 2.8*10^-6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How much will the diameter of the pipe expand due to this pressure?

Comment: Okay, now that you have clarified what your problem is, please edit your post to include that info. I’m not trying to sound rude or anything, I’m only trying to help you improve your post.

Comment: @CrSb0001 read the whole post sir